# Using seekbar in a fragment android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-seekbar

I have attached a fragment to an activity. Inside the fragment, i'm listening to the changes made to the seekbar, but the 'onProgressChanged' method is never accessed. Also, when trying to modify a TextView variable which is also in the fragment, it doesn't modify it's value (the TextView variable should display the value of the seekbar.

Here is the code that i have used:

Main activity

```
public class NearbyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_nearby);

    // add map fragment
    NearbyFragment nearbyFragment = (NearbyFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.nearby_fragment);

    if (nearbyFragment == null) {
        nearbyFragment = NearbyFragment.newInstance();
        getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container_bar, nearbyFragment)
                .commit();
    }
}
```

Fragment

```
public class NearbyFragment extends Fragment implements OnSeekBarChangeListener{
private TextView distance;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_nearby, container, false);

    final SeekBar seekBar  = (SeekBar) rootView.findViewById(R.id.seekBar);

    distance = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.distance);

    seekBar.setProgress(50);
    distance.setText("ass");

    seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_nearby, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int i, boolean b) {
    distance.setText("" + i);
}

@Override
public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

}

@Override
public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

}
```

Fragment xml

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <SeekBar
        android:layout_width="241dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/seekBar"
        android:layout_marginStart="60dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="60dp" />

    <TextView
        android:text="0"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/distance"
        android:gravity="center"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change this line

```
return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_nearby, container, false);
```

to

```
return rootView;
```

in your onCreateView